# Low FPS with shaders on good PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine, minecraft-shader

My Specs:
GTX 1660 Super
Ryzen 5 2600
16gb ram

I used all of the shaders i have currently, and im playing on 1.17.1 optifine. My game is even lagging on lower versions so i don't think it's because of the higher version. I tried using SEUS Shaders, Sildurs, VPlus, BSL And even low chocapic shaders that should run normally. But all of these shaders were running poorly (Around 10-30 fps). Does someone know the reason to that?